# Haefliger trefoil $S^3\hookrightarrow S^6$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, embeddings, smoothing-theory

It is known that the Haefliger trefoil $S^3\hookrightarrow S^6$ is PL trivial but non-trivial smoothly. I wonder, where exactly does the problem come? Consider its tubular neighborhood $T\cong S^3\times D^3$. By the disc bundle theorem its closed complement $C$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times D^4$. Therefore, $S^6$ is presented as a union of $S^3\times D^3$ and $S^2\times D^4$ along some non-trivial diffeomorphism $\phi$ of $S^3\times S^2$. But it follows from the smoothing theory (Burghelea-Lashof) that for any closed 5-fold $M$, $\pi_0 Diff(M)=\pi_0 PL(M)$, because $\pi_i PL_5/O_5 = \pi_i PL/O=0$, $i\leq 6$. In our case, as example, since $S^3\times S^2$ is parallelizable, one has a fiber sequence
$$
Diff(S^3\times S^2) \to PL (S^3\times S^2) \to Map(S^3\times S^2,PL_5/O_5).
$$
Therefore, the non-trivial self-diffeomorphism  of $S^2\times S^3$ is also non-trivial as PL self-homeomorphism. But why we then get a non-trivial knot in the smooth category but not in PL? I thought maybe the problem is that $\phi$ is PL concordant to the identity but is not so smoothly. But these sets of concordance classes are also the same $\pi_0\widetilde{Diff}(S^3\times S^2)=
\pi_0\widetilde{PL}(S^3\times S^2)$ thanks to the fiber sequence
$$
\widetilde{Diff}(S^3\times S^2) \to \widetilde{PL} (S^3\times S^2) \to Map(S^3\times S^2,PL/O).
$$
So, can the smooth non-triviality of the Haefliger trefoil be detected in this decomposition? I am puzzled because it also almost looks like a proof that the Haefliger trefoil is smoothly trivial.

Comment: I don't know smoothing theory to well-enough to help, apologies.  I will be very interested in an answer to this question, as well.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan, for your help bringing in the disc bundle theorem.

Comment: In principle I suppose we could determine the diffeomorphism by staring carefully-enough at the Haefliger trefoil.   If I find some more time, that is what I would do.

Comment: I agree, it is a question about extending the diffeomorphism $\phi$ of the boundary $S^2\times S^3$ inside $S^3\times D^3$ or $S^2\times D^4$, which is possible in PL setting but not smoothly (which is a 6-dimensional problem). However,  I would like to see a quantitative obstruction in terms of smoothing theory if possible.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally deleted my comment. Here again:

Comment: Fix a identification $T=S^3\times D^3$, so $S^3\times *$ and $*\times S^2$ give isotopy classes of embedded $S^2$ and $S^3$ in $C$; let’s call them standard. We also have a standard embedded  $S^2$ and $S^3$ in $S^2\times D^4$. In your "fake-argument", don't you secretly assume that the diffeomorphism $C\cong S^2\times D^4$ preserves the two standard $S^3$? By construction it preserves the standard $S^2$, but it need not preserve the $S^3$. Note that this is now a question about diffeomorphisms of $6$-manifolds, and here the PL- and smooth lands differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that $S^3\subset S^6$ admits more $PL$-framings than smooth ones: $\pi_3 SO_3=\mathbb{Z}$, while $\pi_3 PL_{6,3}=\mathbb{Z}^2$. (The group $PL_{6,3}$ is the group of PL self homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^6$ preserving $\mathbb{R}^3\subset\mathbb{R}^6$ pointwise.) Thus, when we PL isotop the Haefliger trefoil identically to the trivial knot, and we lift this isotopy to its tubular neighborhood $T=S^3\times D^3$, the obtained $PL$-framing of the trivial knot is not smoothable i.e., it does not come from an $SO_3$-framing. In both smooth and PL categories the space of embeddings $T\hookrightarrow S^6$ that send $S^3\times *$ identically to itself is homotopy equivalent to the space of such immersions, while the latter space by Smale-Hirsch-Haefliger-Poenaru is equivalent to $Map(S^3,SO_3)$ and $Map(S^3,PL_{6,3})$, respectively.

Comment: The credit should be given to Arkady Skopenkov for the above answer.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the trefoil's PL tubular neighbourhood in the boundary of $S^3 \times D^3$.